# Uploading an image to MySQL, endless amount of errors

Tags: php, mysql

I've spent most of my day working on this image uploader, after browsing and visitng many many threads and forums I've found several solutions to my problems however I am now at the point where if I try a different solution, something else breaks.

What I've got so far:

```
 <form action="create.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    Select File
    <input type="file" name="upload">

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" />
    <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description" />
    <input type="text" name="category" placeholder="Category" />

</form>
<?php
$conn = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=project;", "root", "0612733771Aa");
```

Full PHP is here, couldnt figure the formatting

https://pastebin.com/LGeuzLRH

The main error I'm getting is this:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && isset($_FILES['upload'])) {
$image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);
if ($image_size === FALSE) {
die("Unable to determine image type of uploaded file");
}
```

Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\Apache24\htdocs\create.php on line 29
Unable to determine image type of uploaded file

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You haven't asked a question or described what's not working. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection attacks**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Nobody is going to write the whole thing for you.  And paste what you have tried

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on SQL injection, will look into that further. Apologies for lack of clarity it's been a long day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call at the end of php file after all the image validations

```
if (move_uploaded_file($image, $any_custom_target_file_path)) {
        echo "The file has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
```

After this you can save the $any_custom_target_file_path in the database. As once the script is executed, tmp file will get deleted so we need to save this to some location.

Comment: Would I use something like dirname() to point the image to a storage location?

Comment: It can be any directory with the file name appended, where do you want to store the image. Provide the absolute path.
Please see the following post
http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-file-upload.php

Comment: Thanks, looking now. However I still have an error which prevents me from testing this, I updated the question, I don't know whether or not you are able to help there as well. Thanks

Comment: You can get the file size by ($_FILES["upload"]["size"] / 1024)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm working on a solution now based upon your input, thanks!